# Why the singular values of $A$ is the positive square root of the eigenvalues of $A^{\top}A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, svd, singular-values

I've tried to look for the answer to this curiosity over the internet, but I couldn't find any explanation that is clear enough.

So here's the question: consider a linear transformation $L\colon\mathbf{V}\to\mathbf{W}$. This linear transformation is represented by an $m\times n$-matrix $A$ of rank $r\leq\min(m,n)$, so $A^{\top}$ is the representation of $L^{-1}\colon\mathbf{W}\to\mathbf{V}$. The book told us that the singular values of $A$ are the positive square root of the eigenvalues of $A^{\top}A$, i.e., let's say $\delta_{1},\ldots,\delta_{r}$, with $\delta_{1}\geq\cdots\geq\delta_{r}>0$, are the eigenvalues of $A^{\top}A$ such that $\sigma_{1},\ldots,\sigma_{r}$ are the singular values of $A$, where $\sigma_{i}=\sqrt{\delta_{i}}$.

But why is it like that? What is the intuitive explanation as to why we choose that the eigenvalues of $A^{\top}A$ are related to the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: If $A=U\Sigma V^*$ is the SVD of $A$ then $A^*A = V\Sigma^T\Sigma V^*$. What can you conclude from this?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3686027/in-svd-why-is-sigma-the-square-root-of-vs-eigen-values

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Thank you for answering! I have noticed that $VV^{\top}$ is just an identity matrix $I$. This concludes that the matrix $\Sigma^{\top}\Sigma$ has the singular values squared on its diagonal. So it immediately shows that $\sigma_{i}=\sqrt{\delta_{i}}$. However, this just proves that $\sigma_{i}=\sqrt{\delta_{i}}$. I'm still curious what's the reasoning behind why we do that?

Comment: One of my favorite interpretations is how $A$ acts on a sphere. Let's suppose you want to measure how much $A$ stretches a sphere. You would then look at $\|Ax\| = \sqrt{x^*A^*Ax}$ for $\|x\|=1$. Where is this stretching locally minimized/maximized? Precisely at the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^TA$. But those are precisely the singular values of $A$, as $\|Ax\| = \|U\Sigma V^* x\| = \|\Sigma V^*x\| = \|\Sigma e_i\| = \sigma_i$ for $x=Ve_i$.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Oh, I see! So that's the interpretation. Thank you for answering my curiosity, it truly amazed me.

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Comment: @V.S.e.H. May I ask you another question? I just happened to think about this: why do we write the eigenvalues $\delta_{1},\ldots,\delta_{r}$ in order, which is decreasing in this case?

Comment: It's easier to reason about that way. Otherwise the order doesn't matter. You can always reorder them via a permutation similarity.